# Paypal API cancelling billing agreement

Tags: php, paypal, sdk

I know there are qiestions asked on this topic already, but i could not find a solution. I am absolutely new at paypal api and my task is to create a function to cancel billing agreement.

Do not even know how to form and make function call api. Tried to find and example, but everywhere i end up viewing technical reference page which does not help me as newbie...

Anyone could draft and example please?

So far i got to this stage, but still won't work.

```
if(!empty($agreement->paypal_agreement_id) && $agreement->paypal_agreement_state == 'Active')
{
    /*
     * Cancel a billing agreement
     */
    $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($this->clientid, $this->clientsecret));
    $createdAgreement = $agreement->paypal_agreement_id;

    $patch = new Patch();

    $patch->setOp('replace')
        ->setPath('/')
        ->setValue(json_decode('{
                "billingagreementstatus": "Canceled"
            }'));
    $patchRequest = new PatchRequest();
    $patchRequest->addPatch($patch);
    try {
        // Uzkomentinta testatimui - netrinti. Mindaugas
        $createdAgreement->update($patchRequest, $apiContext);
        $agreement = Agreement::get($createdAgreement, $apiContext);
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        ResultPrinter::printError("Updated the Agreement with new Description and Updated Shipping Address", "Agreement", null, $patchRequest, $ex);
        exit(1);
    }
} else {
    return ['.reportmsg' => 'Payment agreements do not exist.'];
}
```

Anyone can help?

Comment: Sorry this does not answer your question... Have you looked at stripe? Their API and ethos seem to be light years ahead of paypal.

Comment: unfortunately i need to make this function using paypal api :/